Configure VS Code using settings.json to use ruff instead of pylint, pylance, etc
I am looking to be able to set up settings.json used by VS Code so that I can use ruff instead of pylint, pylance, flake8 linting.  I am hoping to get the rules into settings.json and not have external .toml files.
Here is what my Python settings currently include:
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "charliermarsh.ruff"
    },


How do I tell ruff to turn on rules emulating the different linters?
How do I then tell VS Code to only use ruff?


Install the Ruff extension and uninstall or disable other linting extensions.         https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

I have Ruff extension installed. The question I have is is how to configure. How can I setup Ruff to work as the other linters do (meaning having it find the same class of problems) and how can I disable the others in the settings.json file.

https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-vscode?tab=readme-ov-file#configuring-ruff

I was in the similar situation as you @charles-plager and I had this configuration in VS Code settings.json for Python:

{
//...
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
    "editor.formatOnType": false,
    // For formatting with YAPF install extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eeyore.yapf
    // Then use 'eeyore.yapf' as below for editor.defaultFormatter:
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "eeyore.yapf"
  },
/...
}

In addition to the above configuration, I had been using following VS Code extensions installed:

Python by Microsoft
Pylance by Microsoft, note that this one is installed automatically with (1)
Python Debugger by Microsoft, note that this one is installed automatically with (1)
isort by Microsoft
flake8 by Microsoft
Pylint by Microsoft
yapf by EeyoreLee

After I decided to try Ruff (via VS Code (extension)[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charliermarsh.ruff]) for both linting and formatting, I ended up with these configs and extensions:

VS Code settings.json
 //...
 // Python language environment
 "[python]": {
   "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
   "editor.formatOnType": false,
   // For formatting with YAPF install extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eeyore.yapf
   // Then use 'eeyore.yapf' as below for editor.defaultFormatter:
   // "editor.defaultFormatter": "eeyore.yapf",
   // For formatting with Ruff install extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charliermarsh.ruff
   // Then use 'charliermarsh.ruff' as below for editor.defaultFormatter:
   "editor.formatOnSave": true,
   "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
     "source.fixAll": "explicit",
     "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
   },
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "charliermarsh.ruff",
 },
 "ruff.nativeServer": "on",

 // Python Language Server
 //"python.languageServer": "Pylance",

 // Pylint extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.pylint
 // "pylint.enabled": true,
 // "pylint.lintOnChange": true,
 // "pylint.path" : ["${interpreter}", "-m", "pylint"],
 // "pylint.interpreter": [], // Defaults to extension using the path to the selected Python interpreter 

 // Flake8 extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.flake8
 // "flake8.args": [
 //   "--verbose",
 //   "--max-line-length",
 //   "160",
 //   "--max-complexity",
 //   "10",
 //   "--ignore=E266,E501,C901"
 // ],
 // "flake8.severity": { "convention": "Information", "error": "Error", "fatal": "Error", "refactor": "Hint", "warning": "Warning", "info": "Information" },
 //...


For each project individually, creating .ruff.toml to further configure Ruff behavior and enable/disable rules from other tools implemented in Ruff:
target-version = "py313"
line-length = 160
indent-width = 2
extend-exclude = [".vscode", ".idea", "__pycache__", ".python-version", ".ruff.toml", "ruff.toml", "setup.cfg", "pyproject.toml"]

[format]
indent-style = "space"
line-ending = "lf"
docstring-code-format = true
docstring-code-line-length = 120

[lint]
# D - Enable all `pydocstyle` rules, limiting to those that adhere to the Pep257 convention enabled via `convention = "pep257"` below
select = ["E501", "I", "D"]
ignore = ["D203","D204","D211","D212","D400","D406","D407","E266","C901"]

[lint.pylint]
# Maximum number of arguments for function / method
max-args = 20
# Maximum number of boolean expressions in a if statement
max-bool-expr = 10
# Maximum number of branch for function / method body
max-branches = 100
# Maximum number of locals for function / method body
max-locals = 15
# Maximum number of nested blocks for function / method body
max-nested-blocks = 5
# Maximum number of positional arguments allowed for a function or method definition
max-positional-args = 10
# Maximum number of public methods for a class (see R0904).
max-public-methods = 30
# Maximum number of return statements allowed for a function or method body
max-returns = 10
# Maximum number of statements in function / method body
max-statements = 1000

[lint.pydocstyle]
convention = "pep257"

[lint.mccabe]
max-complexity = 10



Uninstalled all VS Code extensions [4-7] on the above list. I believe Pylance could be also uninstalled, but for now I am still evaluating benefits of using Ruff language server vs. Pylance.

NOTE: My answer is based on that I was facing identical challenge and this is what I ended up with "good working config" for Python development in VS Code. The driving idea is to reduce number of plugins in VS Code for each individual tool, since Ruff covers many of the rules from other tools natively. Hope that helps you and please leave comments about pros vs. cons of using Ruff language server vs. Pylance.

Note that VS Code docs for Profiles (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_python-profile-template) is using Ruff as recommendation and avoids setting "python.languageServer": "Pylance" . I believe this is in order to allow "ruff.nativeServer": "auto" default from Ruff extension to kick in and choose best implementation of language server that Ruff offers (see https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/editors/settings/#nativeserver).
